# my results are rounded, i want the full length answer please

Tags: python, rounding

Here is my code in Python:

```
def my_sqrt(a):
    x=1
    while True:
        y=(x+a/x)/2.0
        if y==x:
            break
        x=y
        return y
```

Output I get:

```
>>> my_sqrt(1.0)
>>> my_sqrt(2)
1.5
```

Looking to get:

```
my_sqrt(1.0)-->1.0
my_sqrt(2)-->1.41421356237
```

Comment: It is not a rounding problem, your algorithm is wrong. You only execute once the while instruction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`return` ends the function and returns immediately. It's indented so it's in the loop and runs unconditionally at the end of the first iteration. Dedent it to run after the loop completes due to `break`:

```
def my_sqrt(a):
    x = 1
    while True:
        y = (x + a / x) / 2.0
        if y == x:
            break
        x = y
    return y
```

Alternatively, since `return` ends the function and thus the loop, you don't even need `break`:

```
def my_sqrt(a):
    x = 1
    while True:
        y = (x + a / x) / 2.0
        if y == x:
            return y
        x = y
```